# Is there a 'general' need for a Silverlight component that will allow Flash FLV video to play?

Tags: flash, video, silverlight-4.0, flv, flvplayback

We have a Silverlight component that will play Flash FLV in Silverlight and are looking to make it available soon; would be glad to hear any views on how this would be received?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be really interesting if it would also support the WP7 platform.

Comment: It's here see 'RealTube' on WP7 review here http://mobilitydigest.com/ms-forget-flash-via-plugin-just-adapt-realtube-natively/